# Add a max-constraint to a gurobi minimize in Java

Tags: java, gurobi

i am trying to implement a maximize constraint to a gurobi minimize problem in java.
I am having a MIP with nodes an armlenghts of geometrical objects which i am minimizing by now.
What i want to implement is min z(x,y) = max{0, distance(x,y)-1,5), because distance values below 1,5mm are compensable with the screwholes where my modules are screwed together.
by now what is implemented is z(x,y) = distance(x,y) (it´s a pretty complex mathematical function and the code has 1000 rows already, if needed i could provide you more information)

Does anybody know how i can implement this max constraint in a minimize problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The max general constraint should do what you want; here is the [Java documentation for the max general constraint](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/java_model_agc_max.html).